# How to Handle Microsoft Oauth2.0 Websites using jmeter

Tags: oauth-2.0, jmeter

I am new to jmeter and now i am doing an performance testing on microsoft oauth 2.0 application . And i am facing problem while Login. And i try to handle it and also able to handle it by Webdriver sampler but i don't want to perform any browser actions .

So can any one suggest me how we can handle it ?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Actually i'm stuck in login only .
1. I am hitting to our website then it automatically redirect to microsoft active directory and Login page is coming with a url containing Client id ,state and Nonce details 
2. Enter Username and password . system will navigate to home page and will provide the Berrer token
3.Now i am handling our login process using webdriver sampler. Which is working perfectly fine

But i don't want to perform any browser action

Comment: @amitpadhy are you still facing this issue ? or you got a resolution